# Are timestamp columns meant respond to boolean method calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I just noticed that I can call boolean methods on AR timestamps. Can I depend on this behaviour, or is it a glitch?

```
foo.updated_at? #=> true if not nil, but false if nil
```

It's useful if I have a `@task.completed_on` column. I can use `completed_on` to determine if the task has been completed (has a timestamp, or is nil).

```
@task.completed?
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def completed?
    completed_on?
  end
end
```

Comment: I doubt it's a glitch as AR uses method_missing to create those methods. They must have created it on purpose.

Comment: [36] pry(main)> User.last.updated_at?
    SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> true   Look what it is executed hope u got what it is

Comment: @RajarshiDas what am I supposed to be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides predicate methods (methods that return a boolean and are suffixed with a question mark) for all attributes in an ActiveRecord model, regardless of the type of the column in the database, returning true if it has a value or false if it is nil. It is not a glitch at all.

You can use this kind of methods both in persisted or recently initialized Models, like this:

```
u = User.find_by(email: "foo@bar.com") 
u.email? # => true

u = User.new(email: "new@user.com")
u.email? # => true
```

You can totally depend on this behavior. It is even recommended for small conditions in your views and an elegant way to write methods as you did in your `completed?` example.